# Count total list elements in a string

Tags: python, string, list, count

I found a syntax issue I couldn't solve or find a solution to online and was hoping someone on here might have the answer. I'm trying to count the number of list elements in a string. I've tried the usual ways like count, isinstance, and set(probably all wrong)

I would like to count how many list elements I have in str1:

```
arr = [1, 'apple', 'banana', 2, 3]
str1 = ("this " + arr[0] + " then " + arr[3] + " next " + arr[2])
```

The output would look something like this: arr[] was used "3" times in str1

Comment: So is your required answer `2` for the `arr`? I have no idea what you're trying to demonstrate with `str1`.

Comment: Can you explain what are you going to do with thing cause it wil make sense.

Comment: Do you mean "I want to count the number of strings in a list"?!

Comment: `"this " + arr[0]` is not valid, it needs to be `"this " + str(arr[0])`

Comment: I've updated what the output should look like. I want to be able to count how many times arr[] was used in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `count()` method to count how many times a substring occurs in a string. And use `sum()` to add up the counts of each list element.

```
total = sum(str1.count(str(i)) for i in arr)
print(f'Str1 contains a total of {total} arr[]')
```

This counts all the duplicate matches separately. If you don't need those separate counts, use `in` to test if the element is in the string.

```
total = sum(str(i) in str1 for i in arr)
```

Comment: I thought this as well but get this error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Didn't you see my earlier comment saying that `"this " + arr[0]` is not valid?

Comment: That error isn't coming from the code in my answer, it's from your incorrect way of creating `str1`.

Comment: Hmm I must be running into an issue with my compiler even just this statement is throwing an error: str1 = ("this " + str(arr[0] + " then " + str(arr[2] + " next " + str(arr[3]) error: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: You're missing some `)`

Comment: `str1 = ("this " + str(arr[0]) + " then " + str(arr[2]) + " next " + str(arr[3])`

Comment: Or use an f-string: `str1 = f"this {arr[0]} then {arr[2]} next {arr[3]}"`

Comment: I got so blinded by the answer I missed the most basic part of the answer, thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

We must add the "str" variable type to the array for them to be counted

```
str1 = ("this " + str(arr[0]) + " then " + str(arr[2]) + " next " + str(arr[3]))
```